# Send json array data from html to Flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I have a variable, called images, in my frontend holding a handful of images selected by the user. 
The following:

```
JSON.stringify(images)
```

would then return

```
["image1", "image2", "image3"]
```

if the user selected the first three images.

I want to POST this array to Flask, make flask do some manipulation and then return the images in a new route. 
My jQuery script for the HTTP post looks as follows:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$("#btn1").click(function(){  
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
url:  "{{ url_for('filter') }}",
dataType : 'json',
data : JSON.stringify(images) 
})
})
})
```

The route responsible for the manipulation looks as follows:

```
 @app.route("/filter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
 def filter():
     if request.method=="POST":
         result=request.get_json()
         ## Do some manipulation to result
 return render_template("result.html",result=result)
```

My problem is that the data retrieved by Flask is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for the response expected from the Flask app server was configured to be `JSON`.

```
dataType: 'json',
```

That is not the right dataType as the Flask server returns HTML in it's response and jQuery runs into error trying to parse it into a JavaScript object.

```
return render_template("result.html", result=result)
```

JSON response can be returned from the server and handle appropriately in the success handler.

```
from flask import jsonify

#...

return jsonify(result)
```

Or the `dataType` for the response set to `html` (for this, you can insert the returned markup piece into HTML document).

Comment: Okay, so I tried both, but it is still like jQuery does not parse any data to Flask. 
Setting dataType='json' and return jsonify(result), returns null in the /filter route

Comment: I'd verify the value of `images` in `JSON.stringify(images)`. I don't see a reason for `request.get_json()` to be `None`